# How do I open a messenger bot URL button in a window frame?

Tags: facebook, bots, messenger

How do I open a messenger bot URL button in a window frame? This way I don't have to open a new tab, instead it will be a popup frame inside the current window.

Answer (score 1):

In mobile Messenger you can set the webview to true
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/messenger-extension

```
"buttons":[
              {
                "type":"web_url",
                "url":"https://petersfancyapparel.com/criteria_selector",
                "title":"Select Criteria",
                "webview_height_ratio": "compact"
              }
        ]
```

This will open your URL inside the Messenger box on mobile. Don't forget to whitelist the URL for this to work.